# submitting form through javascript and passing a variable with it

Tags: javascript, html

I want to submit a form and add a javascript variable with it. I tried using AJAX but that didn't work properly because the form is cut in two parts on the same page. I'm now using a `<button onclick='submit_form()'>send</button>` which calls on the following function:

```
function submit_form()
{
document.getElementById("form2").submit();
}
```

however I need to pass on a javascript variable `current_score` I have it declared and it has a value I just don't know how to add this to my submit function I tried using a return within the function itself and writing a function for it but neither worked :) help and hints are greatly appreciated.
**The idea is that people receive a score fill a form and send it to a database, The ajax script part was to try and pass the values on to the next page that will submit the data**

Comment: Is `current_score` a form value? If not, what is it?

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking.  How did you "try using AJAX"?  Do you have some sample code?

Comment: it's a int variable that's used by another function to calculate a score. The idea is that people receive a score fill a form and send it to a database

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. The simple way would be to append a get parameter to the URL you are requesting. The following example will append a hidden input element to your form:

```
var hidden = document.createElement("input");
hidden.type = "hidden";
hidden.name = "theName";
hidden.value = current_score;
var f = document.getElementById("form2");
f.appendChild(hidden);
f.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the information in window.variable also